# CSS splitting hierarchical list into horizontally arranged hierarchies

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list with multiple top level nodes that I need to lay out horizontally (while retaining vertical layout of child nodes). E.g., for a basic list markup such as:

```
<ol>
     <li>Top 1
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
     </li>
     <li>Top 2
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
     </li>
</ol>
```

Instead of rendering these as a vertically stacked hierarchy, each top level node would start a new column

I.e., instead of

```
Top 1
    Sub 1
    Sub  2
Top 2
    Sub 1
    Sub 2
```

It would be rendered

```
Top 1            Top 2
   Sub 1            Sub 1
   Sub 2            Sub 2
```

etc. My list markup has up to a dozen top-level nodes and is nested 5 deep in some areas.

I know how to render the whole list horizontally, but stumped how to render the top-level node horizontally but all its children vertically.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mark-up is a little incorrect, you need to wrap the child `<li>`'s inside with another `<ol>` so that your mark-up looks like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>Top 1
        <ol>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Top 2
        <ol>
            <li>Sub 1</li>
            <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Next, using the following CSS, you can achieve what you're trying to do:

```
ol li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol li ol li {
    display: block;
}
ol ol {
    padding-left: 5px
}
```

Here's a working demo:

```css
ol li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ol li ol li {
  display: block;
}
ol ol {
  padding-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Top 1
    <ol>
      <li>Sub 1</li>
      <li>Sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Top 2
    <ol>
      <li>Sub 1</li>
      <li>Sub 2</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```